# 800-Calorie Diet

Tags: diet

I am looking for an 800-calorie diet which is suitable for somebody who is allergic to eggs and milk.  I am able to consume soya drink (or "soya milk", as some people refer to it), but am unable to tolerate eggs.  I am lactose intolerant.

However, I am able to consume eggs if they are used as part of a recipe and not a main ingredient.  I am able to consume eggs to some extent when they are used to make bread or cakes, but am unable to tolerate eggs when used in omelettes, for example.

If anybody knows of an 800-calorie diet which is suitable for me and my intolerances, I would love to hear from you.

Thank you so much. Mick

Comment: Why does it have to be an insane 800 Kcal?

Comment: Agree with @Ivo - I'm not sure that a starvation diet like this can be beneficial for any purpose. It's not going to help you lose/keep off weight - your body is going to fight that deficit with vigor and rob muscle, organ, and bone tissues to try to make up for the deficit, while hoarding fat.

Comment: That kind of caloric intake is near what the body needs at a minimum just to function! This kind of extreme diet is for VERY special circumstances and should be used under proper medical supervision.  Check WebMd http://bit.ly/91Nudj

Comment: 1200 calories is the minimum amount of calories that I suggest for anyone.  If you are in a wheelchair 800 calories might make sense but if not, like others have said, it isn't a good idea.

Comment: I was down to 1400 calories a day, and increasing intake on active days, a couple of years ago and was losing weight super fast, no reason to go below that.

Comment: Off topic according to the [FAQ] since the scope change of the site excluded questions not related to exercise.

Comment: Answer below sounds very well for what you need, but this applies as a healty diet, when you live very sedenterily. I would rather suggest creating the caloric deficit by exercise while intake is on maintenance. Adding resistance and cardiovascular exercise to your lifestyle will not only make you happier, but will also ensure you can eat whatever you wanna eat- as long as you count your calories. Simply eat 20% less calories on your inactive days, and maintenance on the resistance or cardio days. That way you will keep your lean body mass and burn the fat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The diet I'm including in my answer is safe, but has a marginally higher daily calorie intake.  It originated with a Dr. Tran in France about 30 years ago, made it to Canada, and about two years ago was approved by the FDA for the USA.  It's typically administered by doctor's offices or health clinics.

**Ideal Protein Diet**

It operates on the basic principle that the modern diet typically has far too much sugar and other insulin inducing chemicals.  As a result, our pancreas gets overworked and produces too much insulin (trapping the calories as fat and making you hungry again).  The diet consists of four phases:

- Phase 1: let the pancreas rest and lose weight. (80-90% of weight loss goal)
- Phase 2: get the stomach used to digesting more whole proteins (remainder of weight loss goal)
- Phase 3: reintroduce carbs safely.
- Phase 4: maintenance

You are given a metered amount of protein, required to eat a certain amount of vegetables, drink at least 10 cups of water, take dietary supplements, and keep a food journal for the administrator to review.  On phase 1 you get about 900 Kcal from the food, with the balance of your daily calorie needs coming from your fat.  The protein is sufficient to protect your muscles and organs, but not enough to exercise strenuously.  I.e. keep your heart rate in the fat burning zone only if you want to work out.  You will eat four meals a day.  Your plan meals come in protein packs which are fairly good, all things considered.

For breakfast, you have a protein pack.  For lunch you have a protein pack and 2 cups of green vegetables.  For dinner, you have your own protein (5 oz lean beef/chicken, or 7oz seafood) plus 2 cups of green vegetables.  Snack is another protein pack.

The protein packs come in the form of soups, cereal, pudding, drinks, etc.  You can have coffee, but every cup you drink requires another cup of water.

Our plan administrators have noted that many women are protein deficient, so when they are on the plan they will actually gain muscle mass.  Me, being a guy, did not experience that side effect--although my wife did.  Average weight loss according to the plan is 3-5 lbs/week for women and 4-7 lbs/week for men.

Additional note: any plan that simply limits calories without a sound medical backing will cause you to lose muscle mass.  Muscle mass is what enables you to burn fat.  When you go off the diet, you will not only gain the weight back quickly, you will gain *more* than you lost.  That is why you need to be smart with the calories you take in.

**Personal Experience**

This plan is monitored, and it helped me drop 85 lbs in 5.5 months.  My wife is still on it right now and she is losing a bit more slowly (70 lbs in 6.5 months so far).  I did have some problems with constipation, but that shouldn't be a surprise considering almost everything with a decent amount of dietary fiber also has carbs and is forbidden in the first phase.

It really helps being creative with your veggies if you are going to be on it for some time.  There were a couple of lower weight loss weeks (1-2 lbs) and some towards the beginning which were much higher.  It's best to be concerned about the inches more than the scale.  When gaining muscle, the inches get smaller even though the scale doesn't move much.

Comment: Nice and comprehensive answer! :-)

Comment: Nice answer. The biggest concern with low-calorie diets like this is that it might "slow" the metabolism so that its difficult to reintroduce carbs or more calories in general. I'd be interested in hearing how phase 3 and 4 have gone for you and what phase 4 looks like in terms of calories, carbs, etc.

Comment: Basically, the way the diet works is that you are still getting all the calories your body burns--it's just that the balance comes from your fat stores.  As to the different phases, I'll add a couple comments.

Comment: Phase 2: essentially like phase 1, except that lunch is now with your own whole protein--just like dinner.

Comment: Phase 3: all carbs are introduced in the morning with none the rest of the day.  It lasts for two weeks.  Essentially, you are covering the different types of carbs your body is likely to see in phase 4 such as fruit, dairy, and grain.  You have some limits for total carbs/fat and a minimum requirement for protein in the meal.  It does seem like a lot all at once though.  The spike in the morning gives your body time to deal with it and get back to burning the fat again by the next day.  Essentially, it is phase 2 with your own breakfast.

Comment: Phase 4: calories are going to be normal for what you need to maintain.  Every meal has a protein.  Breakfast can mix fats and carbs, but that is the only meal that can.  Lunch has protein, veggies and a fat (cheese, salad dressing, nuts, etc).  Dinner has protein, veggies and a carb (rice, whole wheat bread, etc.).  Snack is a protein based snack.  One day a week is a "free day" so you can eat what you like.  Just follow it with a no carb day to compensate.

Comment: As to the slowing of the metabolism, that's what Phase 2 is designed to address.  That's why it is the last 10-20% of your goal, but at least two weeks.  The protein in the plan meals is easily digested (97% absorbable), so you need to "bring the stomach back online" gently--and before you reintroduce carbs.